# Printing all narcisistic numbers at one digit which given by the user

Tags: c, while-loop, nested-loops

I tried to printf all the narcissistic numbers of the number of digits entered by the user.

For example for input `3` the program should print: `153, 370, 371, 407`. Now for some reason instead of printing the numbers it prints nothing and the program is stuck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int digit, a, c = 0;
    unsigned long long int count, b, sum;
    printf("Enter digits to check narcisistic: ");
    scanf("%d", &digit);
    count = pow(10, digit - 1);
    if (digit > 2) {
        while (count < pow(10, digit)) {
            b = count;
            sum = 0;
            while (count >= 1) {
                a = b % 10;
                b /= 10;
                sum += pow(a, digit);
            }
            if (sum == count) {
                printf("\n Narcissistic found:\t%llu", count);
                c++;
            }
            count++;
        }
        if (c == 0)
            printf("No Narcissistic number for this digit.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What is the problem of this code?

Answer (score 5):

```
  while(count>=1){
      a=b%10;
      b/=10;
      sum+=pow(a,digit);
  }
```

`count` never changes in this loop, so it will loop forever.

Answer (score 0):

As per @dcp's answer.
The inner while loop will never exit. What you are supposed to be looping over is the number of digits. For instance (after declaring digNum as an int earlier):

```
    for(digNum = digit; digNum > 0; digNum--)
    {
        a = b%10;
        b /= 10;
        sum+=pow(a,digit);
    }
```

Comment: True, but using a for loop and a variable with a meaningful name makes the intention of the code more obvious. And clean maintainable code is code that doesn't come back to haunt you.